# ionic - subview not showing proper content

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm facing a strange issue with ionic.

I'm trying to create a page (`setup.html`) with two subviews (`roomContent` and `settingsContent`).

My ui-router look like the following:

```
$stateProvider 
.state('setup', {
  url: '/setup',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'setup/setup.html',
  controller: 'setupCtrl',
})
.state('setup.room', {
  url: '/:roomID',
  views: {
    'roomContent': {
      templateUrl: 'setup/room/roomSetup.html',
      controller: 'roomSetupCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('setup.menu', {
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    'settingsContent': {
      templateUrl: 'setup/menu/menuSetup.html'
    }
  }
});
```

and `setup.html`template like this:

```
// This should display content for roomContent (state: setup.room)
<ion-nav-view name="roomContent">
   // ionic tabs here - don't want them on settings subview!
</ion-nav-view>

// This should display content for settingsContent (state: setup.menu)
<ion-nav-view name="settingsContent"></ion-nav-view>
```

But is not working like expected.

Basically, if I go to `roomSetup`, the content is not displayed. If I  change the order of `ion-nav-view` in the html (`settings` before `setup`), then `settings` content is not displayed. It seams like it is displaying only the latest `ion-nav-view`.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**EDIT**

At the end I solved this.

I  changed a bit the folder structure and created a setup state and a new settings state, as I  realized that I have only one setup state but multiple settings. This is the new structure, if it helps:

```
.state('setupRoom', {
  url: '/setup/:roomID',
  templateUrl: './sections/roomSetup/roomSetup.tpl.html',
  controller: 'roomSetupCtrl',
  data: {
    requireLogin: false
  }
}).state('settings', {
  url: '/settings',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: './sections/settings/settings.tpl.html',
  data: {
    requireLogin: false
  }
}).state('settings.menu', {
  views: {
    settingsContent: {
      templateUrl: './sections/settings/menu/menuSettings.tpl.html'
    }
  }
}).state('settings.system', {
  url: '/system',
  views: {
    settingsContent: {
      templateUrl: './sections/settings/system/systemSettings.tpl.html',
      controller: 'settingsSystemCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be defined not as multiple states, but with a single state with multiple views. The way you did, you would need two separate URLs to show at same time. As in UIRouter the URL is attached to the state, this wouldn't be possible.

```
$stateProvider
.state('report',{
views: {
  'filters': {
    templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for filters view ... }
  },
  'tabledata': {
    templateUrl: 'report-table.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for tabledata view ... }
  },
  'graph': {
    templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',
    controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for graph view ... }
  }
}
})
```

See [UI-Router docs about multiple views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but with this method, I  will have them both displayed at the same time, right?
I  actually need to display only one at the time and use setup state as "parent" state to display then settings or menu but not at the same tiume, togheter on the same page

Answer (score 0):

You need nested views :

In setup state configuration

```
views: {
  'setup@': {
    templateUrl: 'setup/setup.html',
    controller: 'setupCtrl'
  }
}
```

and now you use `roomContent@setup` and `settingsContent2@setup`

*Edit:*

If this still does not work you can still try to replace `<ion-nav-view>` by `<div ui-view>`.

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views for more details

Comment: Thanks,but I  probably had to mention that I  need to display only one view at the time, and not both of theme together. I  think this is the way to go if you want (like you said) nested views to be displayed at the same time on the same "parent"page, but that's not really my case